# Overflow @QueryParams Integer in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jsr

Java, Jersey

```
@GET
@Path("/path1")
public String getFunction(
    @QueryParam("param1") Integer intParam1
) {
    ...
}
```

send get request

1. http://domain.cc/path1?param1=1222534625474     // overflow Int
2. http://domain.cc/path1?param1=qweqwe

How to process this errors?
I want to catch the error and throw another (my) error

Comment: But how would you like to process them?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I want to catch the error and throw another (my) error.

Comment: Now I can debug this metod (does not enter the function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1263

```
@GET
public String get(@QueryParam("count") int count, @ErrorParam Map<String, String> errors) {
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(...whatever response you want to generate...);
    }
    ... do whatever you want to do if parameters are fine ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
@GET
@Path("/path1")
public String getFunction(
    @QueryParam("param1") String intParam1Str
) {
    Integer intParam1 = null;
    try {
        intParam1 = Integer.parseInt(intParam1Str");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because the number you are passing in:

> 1222534625474

is larger than the largest integer value java can handle: 2^31-1 or 2147483648.

Try setting the parameter type to long:

```
@GET
@Path("/path1")
public String getFunction(
    @QueryParam("param1") Long intParam1
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: if the number is greater than Long?

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: if the number is greater than Long?

Comment: Then you should accept a string, and try to parse to an integer, long, etc.